How to add <br> tags to a node title?
Saving a node with a title (main node heading) that includes a <br> tag results in a textual <br> in the node title output.
How to add <br> tags to a node title?

By default, the node title is used for both the page title (shown in an <h1> tag in the <body> of the page) and the <title> in the <head> of the page. So, it doesn't support <br> tags because the <title> tag does not support them.
If you want to use <br> tags in the title, you can add a new field to the node entity and use that as the page title, but it will require some custom theming.

But core titles are required. You would end up with duplicate title fields. Not the most efficient way to solve this.

@NoSssweat It depends. The root issue here is that Drupal assumes that the page title and the main heading should always be the same, which is not the case for some sites.

There's the HTML Title module.

Drupal node titles are restrictive and do not support italicized text or superscript text (e.g., Book titles, trademark symbols). The HTML Title module allows a limited set of HTML markup (em, sub, sup, b, i, strong, cite, code, bdi, wbr) to be used in node titles. It filters all other markup from titles to prevent XSS vulnerabilities or irrational nesting (e.g., links within links).
NOTE: few markup options are enabled by default. Desired markup must be enabled in the settings before it will be active.

